# Use AWS Kinesis Video Streams WebRTC SDK C in Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I would like to use AWS's [Kinesis Video Streams for WebRTC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/what-is-kvswebrtc.html) in a MacOS application. I came across a C library on AWS Labs' Github called [amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c) which sounds like what I want however I'm unsure as to how to use it within Swift.

I have built the library from source using their [README](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c#build)–after building I end up with some example executables as well as two `.dylib` files:

[image]

Next I added `libkvsWebrtcClient.dylib` and `libkvsWebrtcSignalingClient.dylib` to my MacOS Xcode Project:

[image]

I am unsure of the next step–how do I reference/use these libraries from Swift?

Answer (score 0):

There is an iOS specific WebRTC SDK that can be used directly: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-ios

Comment: I'm not using iOS–I'm using MacOS.